# Alter sequence to be linked to another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequence, alter, postgresql-9.5

So I'm uploading some 150,000 rows of data into a database over HTTP via Python backend, and the upload takes a while, thus I'm inserting it into a new table which I then swap with (by renaming)  the old table:

```
create table tmp (like main);
alter sequence main_id_seq restart;
alter table tmp alter column id set default nextval('main_id_seq');
drop table main cascade;  -- THIS REMOVES THE SEQUENCE ^^^^^^^
alter table tmp rename to main;
```

How can I alter the sequence to not be linked to the `main` table, so that when I drop the `main` table, the sequence would stay linked to the current `tmp` table (new `main`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by making the column "owning" the sequence

```
alter sequence main_id_seq
  owned by main.id;
```

Comment: Figured there must be a simple way like this, but couldn't find the `owned by` from anywhere... Thanks!

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen: it's right here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersequence.html

Comment: Yeah I gotta read the docs more, I'm still rather new with PSQL. Will make some further research next time, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

[use](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersequence.html) alter sequence:

```
t=# create table s120(i bigserial);
CREATE TABLE
t=# \d+ s120;
                                            Table "public.s120"
 Column |  Type  |                    Modifiers                     | Storage | Stats target | Description
--------+--------+--------------------------------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------
 i      | bigint | not null default nextval('s120_i_seq'::regclass) | plain   |              |

t=# create table s121(i bigint);
CREATE TABLE
t=# alter sequence s120_i_seq owned by s121.i;
ALTER SEQUENCE
t=# drop table s120;
DROP TABLE
t=# alter table s121 alter COLUMN i set default nextval('s120_i_seq'::regclass);
ALTER TABLE
t=# \d+ s121
                                       Table "public.s121"
 Column |  Type  |                Modifiers                | Storage | Stats target | Description
--------+--------+-----------------------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------
 i      | bigint | default nextval('s120_i_seq'::regclass) | plain   |              |
```